# Dont understand why I am getting this error in flutter using image_picker

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, imagepicker

The only error I get here is for the code `File selectedImage;` and the error states "Non-nullable instance field 'selectedImage' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'.

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:tennis_event_app/services/crud.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:random_string/random_string.dart';

class CreateBlog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateBlogState createState() => _CreateBlogState();
}

class _CreateBlogState extends State<CreateBlog> {
  //
  File selectedImage;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  bool isLoading = false;

  CrudMethods crudMethods = new CrudMethods();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        selectedImage = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> uploadBlog() async {
    if (selectedImage != null) {
      // upload the image

      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      Reference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child("blogImages")
          .child("${randomAlphaNumeric(9)}.jpg");

      final UploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(selectedImage);

      var imageUrl;
      await task.whenComplete(() async {
        try {
          imageUrl = await firebaseStorageRef.getDownloadURL();
        } catch (onError) {
          print("Error");
        }

        print(imageUrl);
      });

      // print(downloadUrl);

      Map<String, dynamic> blogData = {
        "imgUrl": imageUrl,
        "author": authorTextEditingController.text,
        "title": titleTextEditingController.text,
        "desc": descTextEditingController.text
      };

      crudMethods.addData(blogData).then((value) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
        Navigator.pop(context);
      });

      // upload the blog info
    }
  }

  //
  TextEditingController titleTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController descTextEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController authorTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Create Blog"),
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              uploadBlog();
            },
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                child: Icon(Icons.file_upload)),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? Container(
              child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ))
          : SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          getImage();
                        },
                        child: selectedImage != null
                            ? Container(
                                height: 150,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                                  child: Image.file(
                                    selectedImage,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            : Container(
                                height: 150,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.camera_alt,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        controller: titleTextEditingController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "enter title"),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        controller: descTextEditingController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "enter desc"),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        controller: authorTextEditingController,
                        decoration:
                            InputDecoration(hintText: "enter author name"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also get two warnings, but not sure if there is really a problem here. this is the warning for lines 37 and 118, "The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true."

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on this for two days!

Comment: Please post the error and a [mre].

Comment: @RocketNikita try using the example located on this page https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker I get the same error when running the code, but instead for the variable ```_image``` and this is straight from the image_picker package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using null safety. So the problem is `File selectedImage` is marked as being not nullable, but you're not initializing it in the constructor. Try replacing it with `File? selectedImage` or `late File selectedImage`.

At lines 37 and 118 remove the ! as it is not necessary.

I suggest you to read https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety as it is explained in great details.

Comment: Wouldnt removing the ! make the if statement do the opposite of what I want? Also, when I put the ?, I get an error stating, "The argument type 'File?' cant be assigned to the parameter type 'File'. If I put late, I get an error in the actual app itself saying "LateinitializationError: Field 'selectedImage' has not been initialized.

Comment: You have to use the ? when you want to accept null values and the ! when you assert your variable is not null (for example when you have explicitly null tested it). For example if you declare 'File? selectedImage' you have to do 'final UploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(selectedImage!);'